# Restrict record from being deleted after being submitted for approval

Tags: salesforce

Fairly new to Salesforce so not sure if this is a dumb question. Once a record has been submitted for an approval process I need to restrict that record from now being able to be deleted EXCEPT for those that have one specific permission set. Wondering what the best way would be to go about this.

Thank you. please let me know if my scenario is not clear. I will try to reword it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading up about "Custom Permissions". It's your own checkboxes you can add to Profile / Permission Set and [checking them doesn't cost a query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/custom_perms_overview.htm). It's faster and less fragile than checking [PermissionSetAssignment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_permissionsetassignment.htm) table for this user and presence of permission set by name.

The act of being in approval process is tracked in [ProcessInstance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_processinstance.htm) table.

No promises it'll compile but something like this should get you started. It assumes the approval is just tracked like that, the related list of approval steps. In real life it's possible you have act of entering approval make change some status(?) picklist on your object so you wouldn't even need a query, you'd just check the value.

```apex
trigger ObjectNameHereTrigger on ObjectName__c (before delete){
    if(!FeatureManagement.checkPermission('permission_set_name'){
        /* This should work if entering approval changes something on your record 
        for(ObjectName__c o : trigger.old){
            if(o.Status__c == 'Pending'){
                o.addError('Nice try, go away');
            }
        }
        */

        /* This will work even if you don't have such shortcut but it uses up 1 query */
        Set<Id> inApproval = new Map<Id, ObjectName__c>([SELECT Id
            FROM ObjectName__c
            WHERE Id IN :trigger.old
                AND Id IN (SELECT TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance WHERE Status IN ('Started', 'Pending'))]).keyset();
        for(ObjectName__c o : trigger.old){
            if(inApproval.contains(o.Id)){
                o.addError('Nice try, go away');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm bit rusty with approvals so you may have to tweak that `WHERE Status...` bit. Especially if ones that completed the approval are off limits too. Maybe you want to allow only `WHERE Status != 'Recalled'`